# How to override something in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The HTML:

```
<a href='#' id='myLink1' class='areaLink activeArea' onClick="myFunction('1')">Click Me 1</a>
<a href='#' id='myLink2' class='areaLink activeArea' onClick="myFunction('2')">Click Me 2</a>
```

CSS:

```
.activeArea { font-weight: bold; }
```

I have the following code runny on document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a.areaLink').click(function() {
        $('a.areaLink').removeClass('activeArea');
    });

});
```

And this code inside the function that executes on the onClick event:

```
function myFunction(num) {

    $('#myLink'+num).addClass('activeArea'); // !important

}
```

OK, so when the page initially loads, visually the links should look like this:

Click Me 1
Click Me 2

When the user clicks on either link, that link should become bold like so:

Click Me 1
**Click Me 2**

So how can I make this line within the function:

```
$('#myLink'+num).addClass('activeArea');
```

**OVERIDE** the code running on document ready?

Comment: When the `<a>` tags are clicked, jQuery is removing the `activeArea` class, while `myFunction` is trying to add it back. It doesn't make any sense. What behavior are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Anurag yes, I have to do it that way because I have other things happening on the onClick like ajax requests specific to other parameters that I will be passing through that function. That's why I can't use the examples people are posting. I need a jQuery's equivalent to the !important of CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just remove the `.removeClass()` from the jQuery click event?

```
function myFunction(num) {
    $('a.areaLink').removeClass('activeArea');
    $('#myLink' + num).addClass('activeArea'); // !important
}
```

Comment: I did something similar except I did it in the document ready:     $('a.areaLink').click(function() {
        $('a.areaLink').removeClass('activeArea');
        $(this).addClass('activeArea');
    });

Answer (score 1):

Remove the inline onclick from your `a` tags. You also do not need to have a function to reference the clicked link. Use `$(this)` instead.

```
$('.areaLink').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('activeArea').siblings().removeClass('activeArea');
});
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/SVVJk/1/

Answer (score 0):

Should work fine.  on document ready only loads once.

Do you want it to be bold the next time the page is loaded for the user?

Also, I believe

```
$(this).addClass('activeArea');
```

Will work as well as the code you have there... you don't need to pass in a number and use this naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

Change your html to this:

```
<a href='#' class='areaLink'>Click Me 1</a>
<a href='#' class='areaLink'>Click Me 2</a>
```

And this is all the JS you need:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.areaLink').bind('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.hasClass('activeArea'))
            return;
        $this.siblings().removeClass('activeArea');
        $this.addClass('activeArea');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify it all by doing the following:

```
<a href='#' id='myLink1' class='areaLink'>Click Me 1</a>
<a href='#' id='myLink2' class='areaLink'>Click Me 2</a>
```

And in your script:

```
 $('a.areaLink').click(function() {
   $(this).addClass('activeArea');
   $(this).siblings('.areaLink').removeClass('activeArea');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing something like this:

```
<a href='#' id='myLink1' class='areaLink activeArea clicker' onClick="myFunction('1')">Click Me 1</a>
<a href='#' id='myLink2' class='areaLink activeArea clicker' onClick="myFunction('2')">Click Me 2</a>
```

notice the clicker class i have added to both.

now use this code

```
$(".clicker").click(function(){
   $(this).addClass("whatever_class_you_want_to_add");
});
```

This means you dont need to worry about the number, because it is already known by the target of $(this)